# Solr Random Ordering Internals

Tags: solr

I am using Random sorting. For Random sorting I am providing seed at run time which is random value from 1001 to 999999.

And the results I am getting are random but not properly distributed. Lets there are 5 results, then in 100 run, approx 20 times each item should come to top. But it is not happening,. One item is coming at top approx 80 times. How should I use random ordering so as the order is fairly distributed.

Also How Random sorting acutally works. How does seed play role? I mean using this seed, solr generates order. So how does it actually does it.? What algo it uses? How can I smartly change random seed?

It depends on number of documents?

Comment: Would you please share your configurations, so that we can reproduce? And how you run your queries...